# Map in android widget

Tags: android, android-maps

I m trying to show map in android widget . But as far as i see there is no mapview in android widget. Anybody please tell me is there any possible way to display a map in android widget?

Answer (score 3):

a Mapview is **NOT** a view that is supported in a widget. As can be noted here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html

> Creating the App Widget layout is simple if you're familiar with XML
>   Layouts. However, you must be aware that App Widget layouts are based
>   on RemoteViews, which do not support every kind of layout or view
>   widget.
>
> A RemoteViews object (and, consequently, an App Widget) can support
>   the following layout classes:
>
> - FrameLayout
> - LinearLayout
> - RelativeLayout
>
> And the following widget classes:
>
> - AnalogClock
> - Button
> - Chronometer
> - ImageButton
> - ImageView
> - ProgressBar
> - TextView
> - ViewFlipper
> - ListView
> - GridView
> - StackView
> - AdapterViewFlipper
>
> Descendants of these classes are not supported.

Comment: yes i already read this document, but i want anyother possible way to display map in android widget, anyway, thanks for ur reply.

Comment: You should **NOT** try as this will cause problems with the overall structure that is android. There is a reason the structure is so fixed.

Comment: ok, can we display tha map as image in widget? Like fetch the map image from google api and convert it as bitmap and show it in widget

Comment: This is possible because an ImageView can be used for that. Good thinking.

Comment: Don't forget to mark my answer, if it provided insight and solved your problem/kept your from going on the wrong path! Srinivas

Comment: just now i fount this way JoxTraex,  http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=9.622414142924805,77.87109375&markers=color:blue|label:S|9.622414142924805,77.87109375&zoom=7&size=147x142&scale=2&sensor=false ,  try the link. It will gives u a static image, and we can show the image in widget, Think everything is possible

Answer (score 2):

You can use simple `ImageView` with [Static Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/intro) and draw over returned image from Google Maps. It's not exactly Google Maps, but it's extremely light weight (which is perfect for app widgets).

Answer (score 0):

If you are app developer, there is no way.

If you can modify the framework, you can.